# How do the "<<" and ">>" operators do I/O?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

I'm making a long awaited return to C++ and there's some basic notation that doesn't really seem to be that prominent in other languages.

If you look at this line of code

```
cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << endl;
```

I realise *what* this does. It write's "firstvalue is x" to the console. x being the value of firstvalue. However, I do not know anything about the "<<" or ">>" double angled brackets. I haven't been able to research them or what they do as I don't know the formal name for them.

My question is, what actually *happens* (step by step) in the above statement? And what are these "<<" for? I think I understand that cout is a standard library function for writing to the console. However I'm used to either objective-c or dot notation. I do not see what object this "cout" function is a member of.

I can understand printf a little more easily, as at least it provides braces for the arguments. e.g. printf("your string here").

Comment: Mandatory reading: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: In this context, `<<` is an [operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and the expression is chaining the results of calls to that operator.

Comment: `cout` is not a function. It is an object, for which the `<<` operator is overloaded.

Comment: If you're coming back to c++, this site is an invaluable reference, and the answers you're looking for are here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C++ allows operator overloading. That means a user-defined type can define its own behavior on built-in operators. In this case the operators are called: `left shift` or `right shift` operators. Those operators have been traditionally been used for bit-shifting, but the standard library repurposes them to symbolize streaming operations.

You can find a list of the available operators in [C and C++ here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Bitwise_operators).

In your case you are streaming a string literal and a value of some type into [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout), which is an object of type [std::basic_ostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream).

**Step-by-Step**

After precedence rules have been applied your code looks like this:

```
((cout << "foobar") << x) << endl;
```

The compiler will basically transform the `object << object` expressions into function calls.

```
operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(cout, "foobar"), x), endl);
```

Then it will figure out which overload to call. (This is really
tricky. For now it should be sufficient to believe that it simply
looks for an overload of `operator<<` with matching arguments).

Most of the built-in overloads for basic_ostream are [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

Comment: The overload that takes the string literal isn't actually a member, it's one of the free functions I linked.

Answer (score 7):

The `<<` operator is the "arithmetic left shift" in C++. For example:

```
3 << 2
```

evaluates to 12. The reason is that the binary representation of 3 is

```
00000011
```

shifting it twice to the left you get

```
00001100
```

and the numeric value of the result is 12.

What it has to do this with output? Nothing at all, actually. However in C++ you can redefine the meaning of operators thanks to overloading. The C++ standard library decided to redefine the meaning of the left-shift operator as sort of a "send-to-stream".

So what happens is that

```
std::cout << "whatever"
```

returns as value `std::cout`, but as side effect it outputs the string "whatever".

The operator was chosen because it had a reasonable precedence (overloading cannot change precedence, and you cannot define new operators) and the shape makes it appear somewhat "natural". Note however that the left-shift operator is just a normal operator and for example there is no guarantee about order of evaluation:

```
std::cout << f() << g() << h();
```

here the output will be the result of calling `f()`, followed by the result of calling `g()` and followed by the result of calling `h()`... but the functions themselves may be are called in a different order and for example `h()` could be called first!

So in a sense the "sequence look" of the operator is misleading, because it's about the sequence of output, but not about the sequence of evaluation.

## C++17 update

In C++17 this design bug was fixed by special casing `<<` operator to ensure left-to-right evaluation. After C++17 in the expression `std::cout << f() << g();` `f` must be called before `g`.

Answer (score 4):

They're referred to as stream insertion (or extraction, in the case of `istream >>`), and are actually a semantic overload of the left-shift and right-shift operators.

So, this:

```
int x = 1 << 1;
```

is a bit shift, but this:

```
std::cout << x;
```

is a stream insertion. You can write it out explicitly as:

```
operator <<(std::cout, x);
```

and get exactly the same result. The conventional format of stream insertion operators (they can be overloaded for user-defined types, so it's not unusual to write your own) is

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, T value);
```

The output stream is returned (by reference) so you can chain calls: your example translates as:

```
operator<< (
  operator<< (
    operator<<(std::cout, "firstvalue"),
    firstvalue
  ),
  std::endl
);
```

---

Oh, and ... `std::cout` (and `std::cerr` etc.) are not functions: they're global objects. The function here is the overloaded `<<` operator. Think of them as `FILE *stdout, *stderr` equivalents.

There are some advantages of C++ iostreams over `printf` et. al:

- type-safety: you can't mistakenly print an integer with `"%f"` and get garbage, because overload resolution automatically selects the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, double)` function at compile time
- support for user-defined types: you can write a stream insertion operator for your whizzy new class, and it will just work, everywhere
- stream abstraction: you can use the same overloads (so you only write them once) to format to stdout and stderr (`cout`/`cerr`), and files (`std::ofstream`) and strings (`std::ostringstream`). There's no need to handle `printf`/`fprintf`/`snprintf` separately.

There are also some disadvantages:

- performance: there is some penalty to all that abstraction, and the generality of the locale system which is configured at runtime
- verbosity: at least for primitive types already supported by `printf`, the format strings are much terser and more expressive

Answer (score 3):

The `<<` is an operator, the same way `+` is an operator and `*` is an operator. In the way the following are equivalent expressions:

```
5 + 3 + 2
((5 + 3) + 2)
```

So are the next two:

```
std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl
((std::cout << "Hello") << std::endl)
```

It's just an operator with two operands. For the fundamental types, the `<<` and `>>` operators are actually known as the left and right shift operators. They perform bitwise shifting. For example, `5 << 1` will shift all the bits in 5 (`0101`) left one place, to get 10 (`1010`).

However, as with most other operators, you can overload the shift operators. In the case of the input/output library, the shift operators are overloaded to provide a natural syntax for input and output to a stream. That's because the directionality of the `<<` and `>>` tokens look like something is flowing one way or the other. With these I/O classes, these operator overloads return a reference to the stream you're performing the operator on so that they can be chained together.

You can overload the shift operators for a particular class by either providing a member function `operator<<` or `operator>>` that takes one argument (the operand to the right of the operator). Alternatively, you can provide non-member function with the same names that take two arguments, the two operands of the operator respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It's syntactic sugar for the following:

```
// Let the function 'print' be a renaming of 'operator<<'
// with T being the type of the object you want to print.
std::ostream& print(std::ostream&, const T&);

// 1) Print "first value is" and then return the stream you
// to which to just printed (ie. cout). 2) Use the returned
// stream to chain function calls and print 'firstValue'.
print(print(std::cout, "first value is"), firstValue);
```